# How to coloring specific region (or grid) on 3d object (i.e. sphere) in matplotlib3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

Firstly, I am sorry for my bad English.

My question is how I can coloring specific region with different color (or grid) on 3d sphere surface in matplolib3d.

[image: Such as that grid at the below image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to color specific regions (cells) using the `facecolors` keyword, which requires a RGB(A) value for each cell. You could either create that manually (a `shape(z)` array of RGB(A) values), but it is also possible to use a colormap for that. For example, using the globe example from [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

# When creating `c` from data, `c` needs to be normalized to {0-1} 
c = np.zeros_like(z)
c[30:40,30:40] = 1

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=plt.cm.PuBu(c))
```

[image]

Or, if you manually want to specify a color:

```
c = np.ones((100,100,4))               # shape(z) x 4 array
c[:,:,:] = [0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 1]          # R,G,B,A color globe
c[30:40,30:40,:] = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 1]  # R,G,B,A color patch
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=c)
```

[image]